# How to reset keyboard after running windows in vmware

Tags: unity, keyboard

Each time I start windows XP in vmware-8.0.4 on my ubuntu 12.04 machine the keyboard status is corrupt.

The super-key no longer works, all the icons in the dock show the shortcut tooltip, the right shift key no longer works (althougt the left shift works fine). This persists till I logout and log back in.

The vmware guest works just fine, it is the hosting environment. I use unity as desktop.

Running debian as guest does not trigger the problem.

Ideally there is a fix for this, but I'll settle for a trick to reset the keyboard in unity to get back to a working environment.

Peter Tillemans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to go to the *keyboard layout* section of the configuration panel and press the *restore default* button. Of course then you need to reset the adjustments made, but it beats rebooting. It also opened the road for some more experimenting to take the edge off the rough edges.